# How can i calculate the 95% confidence interval of an effect size if I have the mean difference score, CI of that difference score

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size, descriptive-statistics, group-differences

Mean difference: 3.7 CI(1.4-6.0)
Cohen's d=0.4 how do i calculate the 95% CI of this effect size?

Answer (score 5):

If you know the sizes of the two groups, you can use the 'tes' function in the 'compute.es' package in R, using the following:
library(compute.es)
tes(t=??, n.1=??, n.2=??)

If you have n1 and n2, you can find t as follows:

```
t = d*sqrt((n1*n2)/(n1+n2))
```

Then you can plug into tes() and it will give you a 95% CI for d=0.4.

For example, if you have n1=99 and n2 = 99, then t = 2.81

The top part of the tes() function will give you the 95% CI for d as:

Mean Differences ES:

```
d [ 95 %CI] = 0.4 [ 0.12 , 0.68 ]
```

You can find a full explanation of Confidence Intervals for effect sizes here:

Cumming, G. & Finch, S. (2001) A primer on the understanding, use, and calculation of confidence intervals that are based on central and noncentral distributions. Educational and Psychological Measurement, 61, 633-649.

Or, alternatively, there is a nice walk-through here:
http://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/methods7/Supplements/Confidence%20Intervals%20on%20Effect%20Size.pdf

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to calculate the CI now (-0.0609-0.8609)

Comment: Great! There's a related post here, in case you're interested why you CI now includes 0 whereas the original one did not: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140344/why-is-the-p-value-for-cohens-d-not-equal-to-the-p-value-of-a-t-test/140361#140361

Comment: Is this the same for paired-samples t-tests?

Comment: does this work for Cohen's q too?

Comment: @grey: you've answered your question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197391/how-to-calculate-95-ci-for-cohens-q Was there something else you were looking for?

Comment: @Jordan Collins: No, that's resolved now, thanks. I don't know why it says I posted this yesterday as it actually was at some point last week.

Comment: Sounds good! Your answer was the answer I was going to give here - just had a look on stats.exchange first.

Comment: @trish: yes this will work for paired-samples t-tests. You might want to read here (which is very clear): http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/ISSS_SC/Module008/isss_m8_introttests/node3.html

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer (Sept 2018):** There is now a function in R called `cohen.d.ci` in the `psych` package.

So for example, you can do obtain confidence intervals on d using the following function:

```
psych::cohen.d.ci(d = .1, n1 = 100, n2 = 100)
```

This would return the following:

```
           lower effect     upper
 [1,] -0.1777814    0.1 0.3772792
```

You can also use it where you have a vector of d effect sizes and sample sizes. For example, you might be doing a meta-analysis. Or you might have a large table where you are reporting many sample sizes:

```
data <- data.frame(d = rep(0.5, 5), n1 = seq(100, 500, 100), n2 = seq(100, 500, 100))
ds <- psych::cohen.d.ci(data$d, data$n1, data$n2)
cbind(data, ds)
```

This yields the following matrix:

```
    d  n1  n2     lower effect     upper
1 0.5 100 100 0.1005884    0.5 0.8969416
2 0.5 200 200 0.2178744    0.5 0.7809048
3 0.5 300 300 0.2697461    0.5 0.7294395
4 0.5 400 400 0.3006463    0.5 0.6987449
5 0.5 500 500 0.3217247    0.5 0.6777884
```

**Original Answer** (Dec 2016):
I found Jordan's answer useful, so I wrapped it up into an R function:

```
cohensd.ci <- function(d, n1, n2, ci = 0.95) {
    library(compute.es)
    t <- d * sqrt((n1 * n2)/(n1 + n2))
    capture.output(
        fit <- compute.es::tes(t = t, n.1 = n1, n.2 = n2, level = 100 * ci),
        file = "NUL"
    )
    c(lower.ci = fit$l.d, upper.ci = fit$u.d)
}
```

So for example, a cohen's d of 0.5 with sample sizes of 100 in each group would be:

```
cohensd.ci(d = 0.5, n1 = 100, n2 = 100)
```

resulting in:

```
lower.ci upper.ci 
    0.22     0.78
```

Comment: I am trying different packages (compute.es, psych, and MBESS) for CI around cohen's d and they yield different results for the same values.  Any idea why?